# Installing linters on Atom using a MacBook

Tags: python, anaconda, coding-style, atom-editor

I am a beginner coder and have installed anaconda and atom on my MacBook. So far everything was working well - until I tried to install linters into Atom. I tried linter-flake8 first with the terminal using pip install flake8, next in atom I installed linter-flake8 and it’s dependencies. Still nothing was happening and no error highlights appeared even when I made deliberate mistakes in a python file. The same problem is happening with linter-pylint.

Can you please advise in the simplest way with basic steps I can take to solve this? Most of the solutions provided online are quite complex and I can’t understand them. Also most solutions center around windows operating systems.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

First install this package https://atom.io/packages/linter
 and you can use this second package for python language https://atom.io/packages/linter-python.

Otherwise you find all linter-package [here](https://atomlinter.github.io/).